# DSolve inverse function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, functions

I trying to solve a differential equation

```
DSolve[{D[r[a], a] == 3 r[a]/a (w - (g *(1 + w)*(1 + r[a]))/(1 + g*r[a])),r[1] == r0}, r, a]
```

But the solution is a function of the InverseFunction and I don't know how solve this differential equation, anyone? please.

Comment: It's likely that there is no closed-form expression for the inverse function. Can you not live with it? An alternative would be to express the solution implicitly as an equation.

Comment: How do you plan to use the solution?  For instance, to obtain numerical values or to plot it?

Comment: to obtain the plot of the analytical solution.

Comment: Try `Block[{g = 2, w = 1, r0 = 1},
 Plot[r[a] /. First@dsol, {a, 0., 5}]
 ]` where `dsol` is what i returned by `DSolve[]`.